# .ebextensions remove preinit script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently on deployment I get:

> Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit/30directories.sh failed

I want to remove the hook entirely using .ebextensions, I am currently using:

/.ebextensions/01-remove-unused.config

```
commands:
  removeunused:
    command: "rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit/30directories.sh"
    ignoreErrors: true

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit/30directories.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      ls
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but what platform of ElasticBeanstalk are you using? **For `64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.0 running Docker 1.11.2` specifically** (and maybe other platforms), I don't believe that there is any way to do this the way that you are describing.

Unfortunately, the `preinit` scripts are executed well before ElasticBeanstalk will inject `.ebextensions` into your environment, and they are only run when a fresh instance is started. To confirm this, you can inspect `/var/log/eb-activity.log` on a freshly deployed ElasticBeanstalk instance, which shows you everything related to the bootstrapping process that AWS logs for you. Search for `Initialization/PreInitStage0/PreInitHook` in this log file, and then also search for `.ebextensions`; you will see that the `preinit` scripts indeed get executed before most everything else, and `.ebextensions` files come much later. (for what it's worth, [this blog post](http://www.jmccc.com/blog/archives/2015/06/17/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-hooks/) might help further help understand which hooks get run at which times)

What you could *potentially* do is configure an `.ebextensions` script to execute before all other non-`preinit` `hooks` scripts that will re-execute (and potentially undo changes from) all of the `preinit` scripts. However, I would guess that this would be more trouble than it is worth, as there are likely unintended side effects that could come from this.

At any rate, these are my findings trying to do something similar. Hopefully, this helps (despite the fact that I haven't technically solved your problem)!